# Success with cookie, fails with JWT: RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent

Tags: flags, authentication-authorization, 9

My Controller is working with cookie auth but failing with [JWT](https://www.drupal.org/project/jwt).  This Controller is supposed to flag an entity for the logged-in user.

If I am using cookie auth, there are no errors and everything works as expected.

But when I try to use JWT, **although the entity does get flagged correctly, I get the following error in the Drupal logs:**

> RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have
> already been sent by
> "/app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php" at line 377. in
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
> (line 150 of
> /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php)

How do I fix this error?

Here's how I'm using JWT auth in Postman:

```
POST http://example.com/api/group_add?_format=json
```

Headers:

- Accept: application/vnd.api+json
- Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
- Cache: no-cache
- Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2MTgyMDk4MjAsImV4cCI6MTYyMzM5MzgyMCwiZHJ1cGFsIjp7InVpZCI6IjI3In19.5uDJMtokLXD6K63H5Ikb-F870EYFMrgE4mItTuTT3bI

Request body:

```
{
    "entity_id": "14"
}
```

As for the Controller, here's **MYMODULE.routing.yml**:

```
MYMOUDLE.api_flagging.http:
  path: '/api/group_add'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\MYMODULE\Controller\ApiFlagging::flag'
  methods: [POST]
  requirements:
    _permission: 'view own commerce_order'
    _format: 'json'
  options:
    no_cache: 'TRUE'
```

Here's **ApiFlagging.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\MYMODULE\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\flag\FlagServiceInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

/**
 * Class ApiFlagging.
 *
 * Https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/3091824#comment-13336379
 */
class ApiFlagging extends ControllerBase {

  const FLAG_ID = 'ABC';

  /**
   * The flag service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\flag\FlagServiceInterface
   */
  protected $flagService;

  /**
   * The serializer.
   *
   * @var \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer
   */
  protected $serializer;

  /**
   * The available serialization formats.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $serializerFormats = [];

  /**
   * Constructs a new ApiFlagging object.
   */
  public function __construct(Serializer $serializer, array $serializer_formats, FlagServiceInterface $flag) {
    $this->serializer = $serializer;
    $this->serializerFormats = $serializer_formats;
    $this->flagService = $flag;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    if ($container->hasParameter('serializer.formats') && $container->has('serializer')) {
      $serializer = $container->get('serializer');
      $formats = $container->getParameter('serializer.formats');
    }
    else {
      $formats = ['json'];
      $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
      $serializer = new Serializer([], $encoders);
    }

    return new static(
      $serializer,
      $formats,
      $container->get('flag')
    );
  }

  /**
   * Flagging.
   */
  public function flag(Request $request) {
    $format = $this->getRequestFormat($request);

    $content = $request->getContent();
    $flagData = $this->serializer->decode($content, $format);
    $flag = $this->flagService->getFlagById(self::FLAG_ID);
    $flaggableEntityTypeId = $flag->getFlaggableEntityTypeId();

    $my_goals = NULL;
    if (array_key_exists('goals', $flagData)) {
      $my_goals = $flagData['goals'];
    }

    $entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage($flaggableEntityTypeId)
      ->load($flagData['entity_id']);

    if ($my_goals === NULL) {
      return new JsonResponse([
        'error_message' => 'Goals not set.',
      ], 400);
    }

    try {
      /** @var \Drupal\flag\Entity\Flagging $flagging */
      $flag->set('field_goals', $my_goals);
      $flagging = $this->flagService->flag($flag, $entity);
    }
    catch (\LogicException $e) {
      $message = $e->getMessage();
      return new JsonResponse([
        'error_message' => $message,
      ], 400);
    }

    return new JsonResponse([
      'message' => 'flag success',
      'flagging_uuid' => $flagging->uuid(),
      'flagging_id' => $flagging->id(),
      'flag_id' => $flagging->getFlagId(),
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Gets the format of the current request.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   *   The current request.
   *
   * @return string
   *   The format of the request.
   */
  protected function getRequestFormat(Request $request) {
    $format = $request->getRequestFormat();
    if (!in_array($format, $this->serializerFormats)) {
      throw new BadRequestHttpException("Unrecognized format: $format.");
    }
    return $format;
  }

}
```

More info:

Here's the rest of the error:

```
#0 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionManager.php(164): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start()
#1 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Session/SessionManager.php(195): Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->startNow()
#2 /app/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Session.php(196): Drupal\Core\Session\SessionManager->save()
#3 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(60): Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session->save()
#4 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#5 /app/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#6 /app/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#7 /app/vendor/asm89/stack-cors/src/Asm89/Stack/Cors.php(49): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#8 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#9 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#10 /app/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#11 /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(708): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#12 /app/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#13 {main}
.
```

When I test using my frontend app, I'm also getting the following error in the browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com/api/group_add' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

When I check the browser dev tools Network tab, I see that the preflight request to `group_add` has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100` header, but the xhr request for `group_add` does not.

Comment: Did you check the stack and did you try without the ```kint()``` I don't know  but maybe this instruction tries to echo something ?

Comment: @SimonVart Removing kint has no effect. I updated the question with some more info; it's also showing a CORS error in my frontend app.

Comment: @PatrickKenny any difference if you add the `jwt` auth method to your route?  `_auth: ['jwt_auth', 'cookie']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I found the problem.

In a `hook_flagging_insert()`, I was redirecting users upon node creation:

```
$response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url);
$response->send();
```

Removing the redirect eliminates the problem with jwt.